# How to dual boot Kali Linux and OS X Yosemite on Late 2008 MacBook Pro

Tags: mac, startup, efi

I've done this before on a previous drive I managed to boot OS X and Kali Linux dual booting with rEFInd. However this time on a new drive and fresh OS X Yosemite install I tried rEFInd, didn't work at all.

I tried rEFIt and thats worked and showed up in the boot menu. Yet once I select either two of the Kali install drives it flashes the Linux logo for a brief second then goes straight to a black screen and stays there.

And yes I've looked at the kali docs too

(Reason for this being a duplicate post to another created a few minuets ago is because I evidently posted on a guest account and couldn't reply)

Comment: Have a look at: [Dual Boot Kali on Mac Hardware](http://docs.kali.org/installation/kali-linux-dual-boot-on-mac-hardware)

Comment: I've tried that

Comment: Are you trying to boot the Kail installer or Kail itself? Also, are you using a DVD or flash drive to install Kail?